# How to create unmanaged DLL using C#?

Tags: c#, dll

I want to create a DLL using C#, which can be then called from VBA in the following manner -

```
Private Declare Function invokePath Lib "\\shared_computer\Projects\somedll\myDLL.dll" (ByVal strUName As String, ByVal strSFile As String) As String
```

The idea is, if the path of the DLL is changed I need to only update the path in the Private Declare function line....

I have searched a lot for it, and also not sure whether this arrangement is possible - where we can call a DLL function from a network path without referencing or registering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not create unmanaged DLLs with C#, as C# is a .NET only language. Use C++.

The only way to use a .NET DLL from unmanaged code (for example VBA) is to use COM interop.

Comment: Although he states "unmanaged" in the title, the request in the question's body (i.e. create a C# DLL to be called from VBA) is very well fulfillable.

Comment: Yes, but as you notice, I didn't say it is impossible to access a .NET DLL from VBA. The question, however, is "how to create unmanaged DLL in C#" - and that is not possible.

Comment: so is it possible to access the dll created in C# using Private Declare Function invokePath Lib "\\shared_computer\Projects\somedll\myDLL.dll" (ByVal strUName As String, ByVal strSFile As String) As String and not adding as reference? Requirement is to keep the path flexible. If it is not possible, we have to switch to C++.

Comment: No. It is possible to access a .NET DLL from VBA through COM interop (=> registration required). It is *not* possible to do what you're describing.

Answer (score 15):

Actually you can.
Check out [unmanagedexports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports)
It is a complete walk-through and you'll be able to create entry points like this:

```
[DllExport("GenerateSomehting", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static int GenerateSomehting(int somevalue, ref IntPtr pointer)
```

and call it just like any other unmanaged dll.

```
[DllImport("MyGenerator.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int GenerateSomehting(int somevalue, ref IntPtr pointer);
```

Comment: Is this can run with any place without .net after generate it?

Comment: Yes, I used to build dll's this way so that Delphi could communicate with it.

Comment: Can the functions that are called make use of other .NET libraries?

Comment: I´ll give that a try!

Comment: Worked nicely for .NET Framework 4.5.2 and platform target x86. Tested with a Delphi Pascal console application. Does not work with newer frameworks 4.6 or 4.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Check P/Invoke here, The article contains a useful table of how to translate managed to unmanaged types, short code examples (in C#), tips and a list of resources.

[Essential P/Invoke](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12121/Essential-P-Invoke)

Comment: P/Invoke would be useful if he wanted to access an unmanaged DLL from C#. But he wants to go the other way. There's no such thing as P/Invoke in VBA.

Answer (score -1):

C# Dll cannot export functions that can be called by any other non-CLR code.

This is not possible.